# How can I filter instances of a model in django, with a queryset value of filter field?

Tags: python, django, filter

I am creating an application in django, and I have the next question:

I want to filet objects of modelA, by the field att1, and I have a queryset of values of the field att1. I mean, my models are:

```
class modelA(models.Model):
    att1 = models.ForeignKey(modelB)
    ...

class modelB(models.Model):
    ...
```

I got a queryset ot objects of modelB, and I want to get all objects of modelA which has as value of att1, any of the values of the queryset of modelB.

How can I do it?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing magic

```
ModelA.objects.filter(att1=queryset of modelB)
```

Comment: try `ModelA.objects.filter(att1__in=queryset of modelB)`

Comment: my queryset of att1 contains [{'age': 2}]

Comment: Then why dont you use `__` relation for forienkeys? i mean `ModelA.objects.filter(att1__age=2`

Answer (score 0):

say you have object B with fields att2 and att3

```
class modelA(models.Model):
    att1 = models.ForeignKey(modelB)


class modelB(models.Model):
   att2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   att3 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

then you filter by doing:
    results = modelA.objects.filter(att1__att2='foo')

hope this helps